# TextView bug workaround needed

Tags: android, textview, android-scroll

I use the following code to create a `TextView` with scrollable content:

```
 textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
 textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
 textView.setText("a line of text");
```

When setting the text with LTR content (Text in English) it works as expected - You see the text and it's scrollable.

When using RTL content, text in Hebrew, the `TextView` will seem empty, the enabled scrolling somehow puts it in an offset. When actually scrolling the View it will reset and correct the issue.

Seems like an Android SDK bug, any idea how I can work around it? Jumpstart the `TextView` with a programmatic scroll gesture? Seems excessive.

You can test yourself with the following code:

```
 textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
 textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
 textView.setText("טקסט בעברית");
```